# How to transmit and receive UDP messages

Tags: excel, vba, udp

I'm trying to establish some client-server connection using Excel VBA. I want to monitor some measuring data, so I chose UDP. I downloaded Packet Sender to test UDP and oswinsck_vba from http://ostrosoft.com/oswinsck.aspx. When I launch the code however I get "Error 429: ActiveX component can’t create object" message. I'm using Win7 (64-bit system) with Office2010. Any suggestions? Is  UDP the right chose for me or I'd be better off with some other protocol?

Comment: Did you install the component?

Comment: I did. I downloaded oswinsck.zip; copied OSWINSCK.dll to c:\Windows\system and registered it from the command line. I also installed oswinsck.exe to c:\Program Files (x86)\OSWINSCK. I checked  whether I have the OstroSoft Component active in the References but it is.